# "Service 'OpenVPN Service' (OpenVPNServiceInteractive) failed to start. Verify that you have sufficient privileges to start system services."

Tags: windows-7, openvpn, services

I am getting failure while trying to install **OpenVPN-2.5.4-I604-amd64**  (Downloaded from https://openvpn.net/community-downloads/) on my Windows 7 machine. The message appears in the middle of installation when it tries to start the service.

Notes:

1. Adding New user into "Log on as a service" policy as described here (https://www.parallels.com/blogs/ras/sufficient-privileges-to-install-system_services/) does not help
2. There is no right click "run as administrator" available for this file

Has anyone faced a similar problem and can give me an advise to solve it, please?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and resolved it by installing the MS redist C++ 2015 libraries.

Figured out it was these by allowing the installation to get to the service start point, leaving it alone, opening services, found the openvpn service failing to start, identified the executable it was trying to run, then running that in an administrative cmd prompt.

I got this error:
`api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll is missing`

from there a quick google search told me I needed to install MS C++ libs.

Really would have been helpful if OpenVPN's installer reported the error its executable was encountering.  Or maybe if C++ libs are a dependency, make sure they are installed and prompt the user to install if not?